# Wich of these... are the best configuration, in Lame v3.100, CMD´s command line?

Tags: mp3, quality, best

I tried and compared all of these preset´s configurations.

The idea is to get and rich out the BEST QUALITY of SOUND POSIBLE, Don´t care the file size. With the best Bass or Low Frecuencies, and not acutes peak of sounds.

Always using Joint Stereo, CBR, 44.1 KHz, Low Pass Filter @ 20.5 KHz (LPF is needed to eliminate too high frecuencies, hiss, crisp, sharp and metals sound... very indesables)

In the CMD, i set this:

1) CMD: path...: lame -mj -V4 -q3 --cbr -b320 --lowpass 20.5 xxx.wav "xxx.mp3"

It is exactly the same that: CMD: lame --preset insane xxx.wav

Mediainfo, it will show, in the Configuration´s Options: -mj V4 q3 -lowpass 20.5

Lame.exe shows: LR: 100.0 - MS %:0.0 - Long: 91.5 - Switch: 5.0 - Short %: 3.7

Other configurations:

2) CMD: lame -V0 -q0 --cbr -b320 --lowpass 20.5 xxx.wav

(Mediainfo shows: -mj -V0 -q0 -lowpass 20.5 ) - CBR

3) CMD: lame -V0 -q0 -b320 --lowpass 20.5 xxx.wav (now, without --cbr)

(Mediainfo: -mj -V0 -q0 -lowpass 20.5 --vbr-new) - VBR

Lame.exe shows: LR: 99.9 - MS %:0.1 - Long: 88.6 - Switch: 6.6 - Short %:4.9

And ¿WHY? the Preset Insane is [-V4 -q3] instead the best [-V0 -q0] ?? or at least [-V4 -q0] ??

[image: -mj -V4 -q3 --cbr -b320 --lowpass 20.5 [preset insane]]

[image: -mj -V0 -q0 -lowpass 20.5]

[image: -mj -V0 -q0 -lowpass 20.5 --vbr-new]

Comment: OK - if file-size is not a problem, you have other choices. I would be considering remaining with WAV or maybe using lossless encoding such as APE or FLAC. In any rate, AAC will get you a much better quality lossy result than MP3. OPUS will get you a much better result than AAC. So, if you want to go lossy - go opus. If you want lossless then you have lots of choice there too. If file-size isn't an issue - stay with WAV.

Comment: Hi, i already stored in .wav ripped of comercial CDs. But my old mp3 player Sony plays .mp3 and all music of my cellphone are in mp3 too.

Comment: @Sebastián - what is your use case? otherwise we cannot answer this. All could be correct, and Mark's suggestion of staying with wav is probably the best